# Datepicker Error In Angularjs Application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I am building a web application in angular js and when I try to include a date picker it shows an error such as **"elem.datepicker is not a function"**

I referred [this link for the datepicker](http://codepen.io/n0m4dz/pen/nKLju) code which has the live demo.

The below is my code which will injected to the index page of angularjs application

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
  <p>{{datePicker || "00/00/0000"}}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="datePicker" datepicker />
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive("datepicker", function () {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      var updateModel = function (dateText) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(dateText);
        });
      };
      var options = {
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText) {
          updateModel(dateText);
        }
      };
      elem.datepicker(options);
    }
  }
});
```

I tried lot to solve this but I couldn't.

Comment: Try use datepicker offered by [angular-bootstrap-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)?

Comment: Can you make a plunkr for this question? I can't think of how your `elem` COULD have a datepicker function without injecting a third party library.

Comment: Do you have jquery.js and datepicker.js included in your page?

Comment: @TomA use this http://codepen.io/n0m4dz/pen/nKLju link for the live demo

Comment: @Josep this link http://codepen.io/n0m4dz/pen/nKLju doesn't provided any library for datepicker.js but i have jquery.js in my page

Comment: @sathishkumar no, it has: jquery.js and jquery-ui.js (which has the datepicker in it), do you have jquery-ui with date-picker in your page? I'm afraid that you don't. That's your problem.

Comment: @Josep I have jquery.js but doesn't have the jquery-ui.js

Comment: @sathishkumar you need to include jquery-ui, make sure that when you chose your build of jquery-ui you select the date-picker.

Comment: @joesp I have downloaded the jquery-ui.js from here http://jqueryui.com/ and used it but now also the same error

Comment: @sathishkumar go here: http://jqueryui.com/download/ make sure that you have the Datepicker widget selected, and then in your scripts you should load them in this order: 1) Jquery 2) Jquery-UI 3) AngularJS

Comment: @Josep I have downloaded from the link you have given but it also shows the same error I think it is error in the elem funtion what i need to include for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my computer your code works fine, i think you forgot to import js files ,

add angular bootstrap ,jquery ,bootstrap

-ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.5.0.js
-jquery-1.7.2.min.js
-bootstrap-combined.min.css

Comment: Good job at making an answer for something that has already been answered in the comments, very lame!

Comment: @Furkan can you please list the js files needed to be included

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should look like this with below libraries to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
  <p>{{datePicker || "00/00/0000"}}</p>
  <input type="text" ng-model="datePicker" datepicker />
</div>
</html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="myApp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Include JQuery before angular, then elem is already a jquery object and then you can use it without $()

I had the same problem. I first fixed it by wrapping elem in $():

```
$(elem).datepicker(options);
```

But the correct way to fix this is to include the libraries in the right order.